# crop wrld_simpl gives error after R update

Tags: raster, r, rgeos, maptools

This code was working for me before I updated R to 4.0, but now it throws an error. I get this error on a Mac and a PC. I updated gdal on my mac, but this did not help. I made sure the rgeos package is up to date. It does not seem to be related to the extent I choose (i.e. extent(-180, 180, 50, 90) throws the same error).

```
data("wrld_simpl", package = "maptools") 
out <- crop(wrld_simpl, extent(130, 180, 40, 70))

x[i, ] is invalid
Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, unaryUnion_if_byid_false,  : 
  TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 143.66192817999999 49.312211990000002 at 143.66192817999999 49.312211990000002
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :
  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 143.66192817999999 49.312211990000002
2: In rgeos::gIntersection(x[i, ], y, byid = TRUE, drop_lower_td = TRUE) :
  Invalid objects found; consider using set_RGEOS_CheckValidity(2L)
```

Comment: You could see which feature in `wrld_simpl` is/are causing this by cropping subsets - eg if `out <- crop(wrld_simpl[1:123,], extent(130, 180, 40, 70))` fails you know there's something bad in the first 123 rows. If that works then the bad polygon is in the second 123 rows (I see 246 total rows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of changes in the `rgeos` package. The problem appears to go away if you do as the error message says: *consider using set_RGEOS_CheckValidity(2L)*

```
library(raster)
library(maptools)
data("wrld_simpl") 
out <- crop(wrld_simpl, extent(130, 180, 40, 70))

#x[i, ] is invalid
#Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, unaryUnion_if_byid_false,  : 
#  TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 143.66192817999999 49.312211990000002 at 143.66192817999999 49.312211990000002
#In addition: Warning messages:
#1: In RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :
#  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 143.66192817999999 49.312211990000002
#2: In rgeos::gIntersection(x[i, ], y, byid = TRUE, drop_lower_td = TRUE) :
#  Invalid objects found; consider using set_RGEOS_CheckValidity(2L)
```

Now change the rgeos setting and try again

```
rgeos::set_RGEOS_CheckValidity(2L)
out <- crop(wrld_simpl, extent(130, 180, 40, 70))

#x[i, ] is invalid
#Attempting to make x[i, ] valid by zero-width buffering
#Warning message:
#In RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :
#  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 143.66192817999999 49.312211990000002
```

Still a lot of messages, but not an error.